# How to create squiggle formation on food

Tags: modeling, mesh

I am having trouble making this squiggle part on the pie, could anyone help me? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the part along the edge or the white cream dot at the center of the slice??

Comment: the one along the edge sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try with a curve, begin with a curve that follows the shape:

[image]

Give it thickness (*Bevel > Round* and increase the *Depth*):

[image]

Rotate the vertices individually so that the shape is a bit twisted (here on Y):

[image]

Decrease the resolution and convert to mesh, give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier:

[image]

Sculpt with the *Flatten*, the *Grab* and other brushes:

[image]

Maybe apply the *Subdivision Surface* modifier and sculpt more details...

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a lifesaver!

Comment: moonboots and his pastries... :))

Comment: for the moment it looks more like a tooth paste though   ;)

Comment: ever considered opening your own Blender bakery..?